# Get all members discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've got a question, I need to get a list from all members from all servers where the bot is online(I'm using discord.py rewrite), Right now I have this code-snipped:

```
@bot.command()
async def members(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
```

The program outputs the Bots name 3 times because the bot is on 3 servers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like an `Intents` issue. You need to enable the `members` intent when creating your `commands.Bot` instance, and pass your intents into it.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(intents=intents, prefix_and_other_things_go_here)
```

You also have to enable it in your developer portal. More info on how & where: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. However you require the `Members Intent`

You will have to enable it [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Select the application you want it on -> Select `Bot` -> SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and then make sure it shows blue next to it. Then click Save Changes. Since you are developing your bot you might want to enable Presence intent as well to save you time later.

You will then have to edit your bot variable like so:

```py
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a one-liner solution

```
@client.command()
async def getmember(ctx,member:str):
    print([i.name+'#'+i.discriminator for i in ctx.message.guild.members if member in i.name+'#'+i.discriminator])
```