# Discord.py get member of the server without bots

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there a way to get only the members without the bots of a server?

```
@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    guild = bot.get_guild("guild")

    await ctx.send(f'{guild.member_count}')
```

When I run this code, it sends a message with the member count including bots. I want it to only send me the REAL member count (no bots)!

Comment: `guild.get_guild` that doesn't exist... Also I'm having a tough time understanding your question, can you please edit it and clarify some things?

Comment: We really don't understand much from your question. Can you clarify things more? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I hope you guys can understand it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the `members` intent (so your bot can see the whole members list, not just itself), then count up the number of non-bots in the list of members. Here's how...

```
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

# Enable the default intents, then specifically enable "members".
intents = Intents.default()
intents.members = True

# Initialize the bot with our customized intents object.
bot = Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    # Booleans can be added up; True is 1 and False is 0.
    num_members = sum(not member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members)
    # Sending an integer is fine; we don't need to convert it to a
    # string first.
    await ctx.send(num_members)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

For most [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html), your bot can freely opt in or out of them, straight from Python. However, `members` is a [*privileged* intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#privileged-intents). In order to subscribe to it, you'll also need to enable it in Discord's developer web interface:

[image: Enabling members intent]

Comment: Yes I forgot to do intents=intents in bot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mangoeis For future questions, this is one of the reasons why supplying a full [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is requested and encouraged. We would have seen that and figured out what the specific issue was.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```py
members = 0
for member in ctx.guild.members:
    if not member.bot:
        members += 1
```

using `.bot` checks if the account is a bot or not.

Comment: Yeah this should work but it always sends an 0 but there are 2 members on the server.

Comment: It still sends a 0... it should work but idk why it doesn't work

Comment: @mangoeis make sure to enable intents. Refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65808190/get-all-members-discord-py/65808286#65808286

Comment: Works for me now. I forgot to put intents=intents in bot. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [`discord.Guild.members` property](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members) to get all of the members in the guild. Then, use [`discord.Member.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.bot) to check if each member is a bot.

This would simply be:

```py
humans = []
for member in ctx.guild.members:
    if not member.bot:
        humans.append(member)
num_humans = len(humans)
```

Or, for the list comprehension enthusiasts:

```py
humans = [m for m in ctx.guild.members if not m.bot]
num_humans = len(humans)
```

*Note: This assumes that you have all the necessary intents activate.*