# I can't get the list of all the members in a guild discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to print out all the names of all the members in all the servers my bot is in.
This is my code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        print(guild.name)
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member.name)
```

This prints all the guild names, but only prints the bot's own name, how can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all members discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65808190/get-all-members-discord-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to your bot:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

to get access for members information:

docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#intents

Comment: Providing code with no explanation is not helpful. Please also explain it, provide links where to activate Intents etc. - There are a few things missing here.

Comment: I edit it and add a helpful link for you